# favorite jobs clicked right container still telling me to view all favorites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've got my eye on a few places from the jobs section by making them a favorite.  After you've reached more then 3 favorites the right container adds a link to view all favorites as shown:

[image]

After clicking the link I am taken to my job favorites, I think the site no longer needs to tell me I have x number of favorites with a link as I am already on my favorites:

[image]

Comment: Nice catch, that's a waste of sidebar space. We're re-using a view here and not handling this situation appropriately. Fix is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report - the full favorites listing no longer shows the favorites sidebar module.